# Disable text-selection ONLY on break line characters/characters between elements

Tags: html, css

The CSS `user-select:none` disables all the text selection from an element or the whole document, but I have no clue how do disable the selection between lines or between elements.

#### Example:

```
<body>
  <input value="Ctrl + A">Outside the input<br>There's a character selected after the A and another after the input.
</body>
```

I have tried putting the text inside `<span>`s, disable selection in the body and enable it in the elements, but that will kind of disables it's normal selection. If I click on the body and drag over the span it won't select character by character.

How the example looks like (top) and how I want it to look like (bottom):

[image]

Comment: Please click the `<>` and provide a [mcve]. It is quite hard to understand what your issue is

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting comments. I did this for you now

Comment: I would advise against trying to break this native functionality.  At least for the "Outside the input" part, I think it's highlighting the return character equivalent (as a result of having a break tag there).

Comment: @JosephMarikle - I know, I know, but still. Is it not possible unless with lots of javascript "hacks"? I wonder because such task shouldn't be hard and someone should have already tough about that.

Comment: I personally hate it when I select text and it does that.